# Why some area of my diffuse cycles bake result looks pixelated?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking

[image]

Why some area of my diffuse cycles bake result looks pixelated? I did it in Blender 2.79b

[Blend file](https://pasteall.org/blend/b70fb4a9894744eca159dd50b827c579)

But in Blender 3.0, it can bake flawlessly. Is this a bug of older Blender?

Comment: how do I pin this question to get warned when someone answers it? I need to know too

Comment: Have you checked if the normals are okay?

Comment: Normals ok. Pointing outside

Comment: Could you upload the blend file?

Comment: @RPGlife You can click on Follow to receive notifications about activities in this post.

Comment: @RPGlife: just click on "Follow"

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka Yes, I've uploaded the file.

Comment: It seems like a problem with 2.7, indeed, In 2.8+ it works fine.